# Programmatically, alter the date_format of a field in a view.

Tags: views, datetime

I'm using Drupal 7 and I need to alter, programmatically, the date_format of a field in a view.
I'm using the hook_views_pre_build where I added these lines

```
if ($view->name == 'my_view') {
  $view->display['page']->handler->display->display_options['fields']['my_field']['date_format'] = 'my_format';
}
```

but it doesn't alter the old date_format value.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Can't you use the custom date format option within the views UI? Why do you need to do this programmatically?

Comment: I have a multi-sites and I have to change that field for only one site. So I was trying to use a custom feature for that site.